# How to calculate laplace and laplace inverse using Octave?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, octave

I have Octave installed in my Ubuntu 14.04, and I installed the symbolic package too. When I use the ilaplace function I get this error message:

```
error: 'ilaplace' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

I need to compute laplace and inverse laplace.

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: Did you load the `symbolic` package in your workspace?

Comment: I use it as follow

    s = sym('s')
    ilaplace(1/s^2)

Comment: Describe at least how you've installed the package, what versions of the package, Octave, sympy, python and so on.

Comment: octave version 3.8.1 symbolic 1.1.0, installed with sudo apt-get install octave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show HOW you use ilaplace (always include a minimalistic example which shows your problem). It works for me:

```
pkg load symbolic
ilaplace(sym("1/s^2"))
ans = (sym) t
```

Comment: What versions do you have for both Octave and the symbolic package? (`ver` should tell you)

Comment: octave version 3.8.1
symbolic 1.1.0

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know there never was an v1.1.0 release... laplace was added with octsympy 0.1.3 (2015-01-06)

Comment: I think your installed version is too old. See here http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Octave.27s_Personal_Package_Archive_.28PPA.29_for_Ubuntu to intall Octave 4.0 and consider installing symbolic package from forge